# Using printf in "find" command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

With the following command, I want to find a specific file name, print its name and then compress it in-place with bzip2 command. The compression works but file name is not printed.

```
$ find . -name *.sb.* -printf "%f\n" | xargs bzip2
$ ls
foo.sb.txt.bzip2
$
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Where do you expect it be printed? It _is_ printed to stdout, then passed through the pipe and consumed by xargs and passed as argument to bzip2. If it weren't printed, nothing would happen, because there are no filenames for bzip2 to be compressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to replace your command with:

```
find . -name "*.sb.*" -print -exec bzip2 {} \;
```